# Regexmatch in data validation - working in test site but not sheets

Tags: regex, validation, google-sheets, formatting

I am trying to write a data validation formula such that the following formats are allowed.

```
DD/MM/YYYY - HH:MM:SS
DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS
DD/MM/YYYY - HH:MM
DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM
```

The regex formula that I have tired is
`^[0-3]\d\/[0-2]\d\/[12][90]\d\d\s(\-\s)?\d\d:\d\d(.+)?`

with the sheets code being
`=regexmatch(rept(A1, 1), "^[0-3]\d\/[0-2]\d\/[12][90]\d\\d\s(\-\s)?\d\d:\d\d(.+)?")`

https://regex101.com/ says this should work, but in google sheets it continues to say it doesn't.

The part which checks `DD/MM/YYYY` and `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM(:SS)` works. but I can't get it to check " - " and " " between the two combined texts.

Breaking it down just to the divider check,
both `\d\s(\-\s)?\d` and `[[:space:]](\-[[:space:]])?` don't work in sheets.

Thanks!

Edit:
Found the issue, google sheets is adding in two types of spaces, unicode 32 and 160, looking into how to reference both now.
This is why when pasting it into regex101 the code works, because it is reading it as only character 32 while sheets sees it as both 32 and 160.

And... data validation reads the typed out 160 character as 32...

Comment: Google sheets appears to be adding in a space which isn't the standard space? This seems to be the issue where it is breaking.

Answer (score -1):

It will be difficult to actually *validate* your dates via regex, because of the leap year problem.  If you just want to *match* the four patterns you specified, then use:

```
^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} (- )?\d{2}:\d{2}(:\d{2})?$
```

Comment: using just " " doesn't work, even with \s or [[:space:]] this formula doesn't work.

Comment: I am guessing that the problem is your data, which perhaps has stray leading/trailing whitespace.  My regex is working [in the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/10xr05/1).

Comment: It is working for the last 3 cases, but still failing with the first on the actual sheet? You are right that " " does work, apologies. I've made my test sheet editable briefly if you'd like to have a look?

Comment: Please check the demo, where the pattern is working for all 4 variants.

Comment: I know it works in the regex101, the issue is it doesn't work in sheets. There are no leading or trailing while spaces. I've tested my original code there and it worked.

Comment: You need to debug this and figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was uni char 160, or Hex 00A0, since I can't use the typed version of this character in data validation I needed to use `\x{0A0}`
To avoid dealing with every combination of these types of spaces and - i used the following:

```
=regexmatch(REGEXREPLACE(REPT(A15,1),"\x{0A0}"," "), "^[0-3]\d\/[0-2]\d\/[12][90]\d{2}( )? (- )?(- )?[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d(.+)?")
```

So I've made it replace any occurrence of `\x{0A0}` with the standard space. Then proceed to match this to the format.

Thanks for the feedback all, forcing me to actually figure out what was breaking.